# Can I pay taxes in Spain while working in Germany?

Tags: taxes, germany, spain

I'm actually working in Germany for just 2 months (July and August), and I would like to know if it is possible to pay the taxes in my country (Spain). The advantage of it is that in Spain the taxes are around 25% of the salary, while in Germany this value increases up to 35% more or less. If it is possible, how could I ask for the difference?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: IIRC, the [general EU rule](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/work/taxes/double-taxation/index_en.htm)  is that you pay taxes in both countries, but in the country where you are resident you can take a deduction for taxes already paid in other EU countries. [German-Spanish tax treaty](http://www.agenciatributaria.es/AEAT.internet/Inicio/La_Agencia_Tributaria/Normativa/Fiscalidad_Internacional/Convenios_de_doble_imposicion_firmados_por_Espana/Alemania/Alemania.shtml)

Comment: The websites you provided were really helpful. I guess I will need to call to the German and Spanish tax offices to know what I should do. Thanks for the help! @MSalters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An annual salary lower than EUR 8,354 for singles or EUR 16,708 for a married couple will not be subject to PAYE taxes in Germany when talking about "income from employed work". Since you will only be working for two months, I am assuming you will **not** make more than EUR 4,177 per month, and in that case you do not need to pay tax.[1]

It is possible however that this money needs to be taxed in Spain after you return, this is something you should ask your local tax authorities.

If you are self-employed rather than employed by the company you will be working for, you should contact a tax advisor.

[1] https://www.internations.org/germany-expats/guide/15984-social-security-taxation/taxes-in-germany-15969

Comment: I have a salary of EUR 13,62 per hour (EUR 2300 per month), but just for two months. So what I guess you mean is that, what I will finally earn, extended to 12 months, will be less than that limit, so I would not need to pay taxes. Anyway the company I am working for has already "retained" a huge amount of my salary as a "taxes" concept. So, who should I contact to get the money back, or in a worse case, pay the taxes in Spain? I went to the "Finanzamt" and they could not help me. Thanks for your help! @pzkpfw

Comment: @Zarauztarra: You'll need to file a German tax declaration over 2017. When processed, they'll find you earned no taxable income in Germany after August, and overpaid as a result, so you'll get a refund in 2018.

Comment: So the proccess explained in [link](https://www.settle-in-berlin.com/tax-return-germany-steuererklaerung-english-for-foreigners/) would be enough? Thanks for the answer! @MSalters

Comment: @Zarauztarra : looks sensible.